# Rails rescue_from stops execution flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm having problems using the rescue_from

```
class SimpleError < StandardError; end

before_action :raise_exception
rescue_from SimpleError, with: :rescue_exception    

def raise_exception
    raise SimpleError
end

def rescue_exception
    log $!
end

def index
    @unreachable_code = true
def
```

In this code as you can see I simply raise an exception before the action starts, that is caught by the rescue_exception method. The problem is that after I catch the exception the application flow stops and the action code is never reached.
Is it possible to continue the execution after the exception is rescued?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer, no. `rescue_from` is intended to handle exceptions that are otherwise uncaught.

If you want to catch a particular exception for every action in a controller, I would recommend an [`around_action`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#after-filters-and-around-filters).

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  class SimpleError < StandardError; end

  around_action :handle_simple_errors

  def index
    # code that might raise SimpleError
    @unreachable_code = true
  def

  private

  def handle_simple_errors
    begin
      yield
    rescue SimpleError
      # handle SimpleError however
    end
  end
end
```